# Wifi connection continuously cuts out

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, network, wifi

I have been having an issue I can't seem to fix. The WIFI on my 2017 Macbook Pro keeps cutting out, about once every 10-20 minutes. When this happens I lose internet connection and when I click on the wifi icon in the menu bar it shows that my wifi is on and connected to my network, but my network, as well as all other available wifi networks, are greyed out and I am unable to click anything. Turning the wifi off and back on temporarily fixes the problem.

Here is a list of things I have tried so far:

- Restart computer
- Turn wifi on/off
- Remove network and reconnect
- Remove wifi service and reestablish
- Reboot router
- Factory restore of router
- New SSID, new channels, new wifi password
- Reset the PRAM & SMC
- Updated the Mac OS to Big Sur (from Catalina)
- Ran Wireless Diagnostics

Running Wireless Diagnostics initially finds nothing when the internet is working, but then when this happened it does detect a "Dropped Wi-Fi Connection", stating that:

> Your Mac experienced an unexpected Wi-Fi connection drop, which can be
> caused by a combination of environment, configuration, and software
> problems.
>
> Provide the diagnostics report created in /var/tmp to an AppleCare
> customer support representative for further analysis.

I looked into the logs, but am not really sure what I am looking at. And to make matters worse the applecare on this machine just expired.

Also worth noting that the network has been, and continues to work fine for all other devices (another macbook pro, two iphones, smart tv, etc.) and nothing major changed with the network before this occurred.

Any tips on what to try next?

Comment: It sounds like it *did* work as expected. Can you think of something that might have started/caused this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about Wireless Diagnostics? Yes it did work to detect the problem.

Unfortunately no, nothing major has changed that would have caused this. Started suddenly without any major cause. 

Thanks.

Comment: No I was referring to general connectivity, i.e. did the WiFi connection work some time back and can you remember when that changed and why that may have changed. Or has it never been working?

Comment: oh sorry for the misunderstanding. yes, it has up until this point always worked as expected. have had this current router set-up for about a year with no issues.

Comment: Do you live an area with other WiFi networks, like an apartment building or suburban area? Do you see other networks pop-up in the WiFi Preferences that you've never seen before? Did you get a new microwave oven? Do you have an external USB drive of any sort, either newly connected to the MBP, or recently moved to a new location on your desk / plugged into a different port than usual?

Comment: Yes, I live in an apt building with lots of other WiFI networks. I have chosen channels that aren't being used by other routers, and this has worked fine for all devices for the last year.

No new appliances, USB drives, or locations.